# ¿Cómo tratar con el tema de permisos o "Forbidden" en linux?

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos7

Estoy usando centOs 7. Todo funciona bien. El servidor funciona, porque puedo acceder a la pagina de inicio(**registroseventos.php**).El problema está en que cuando presiono el botón registrar del formulario me sale esto(la segunda imagen). Cuando me dirige al archivo **accion.php**
La carpeta raíz o dirección en la que se encuentran esos archivos es **/var/www/html/**
Estoy agotado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya revisaste los permisos? parece un problema de permisos con apache

Comment: @EgonStetmann. En el archivo httpd.conf???

Comment: si, configurar apache es un problema cuando no sabes manejar simbolos y no te sabes la documentacion. Lo cual lleva tiempo aprender. Revisa un tutorial de youtube sobre como configurar apache correctamente.

Comment: cuales son los permisos de ese script? Si no se corresponden con los permisos de `registroseventos.php`, ponlos igual y probablemente con eso se resuelve.

Comment: @eftshift0 ¿Dónde se los asigno?

Comment: en los archivos.... o sea, en el _File System_ donde están puestos los scripts.

Comment: Si alguien puede hasta por Teamviewer seria una ayuda, quiero salir de esto.Soy nuevo en esto de linux.Lo poco que sé lo he aprendido en una semana.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS viene con SELinux ( security enhanced ) que maneja contextos para ( entre otras cosas ) permitir leer o escribir archivos.

Así que además de los permisos habituales ( [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) ), el dueño y el grupo del archivo o carpeta ( [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) ), también hay que revisar/especificar el contexto ( [chcon](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) ).

Podés revisar los contextos con

```
ls -Z /var/www/html/misitio/
```

En lineas generales:

```sh
# seteamos dueño y grupo -R = recursivo
sudo chown apache:apache -R /var/www/html/misitio

# entramos a la carpeta para que los find siguientes no modifiquen otra cosa
cd /var/www/html/misitio

# permisos de archivos: 
# tipo file, lectura y escritura para el dueño ( 4 + 2 = 6 ) 
# lectura para el grupo y otros ( 4 ) 
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

# permisos de carpetas:
# tipo directory, lectura, escritura, ejecución para el dueño ( 4 + 2 + 1 = 7 )
# lectura y ejecución para el grupo y otros ( 4 + 1 = 5 ) 
# el bit ejecución en carpetas significa poder listar/entrar en la carpeta
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;

# SELinux el contexto apache puede servir estos archivos/carpetas
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/misitio -R

# SELinux el contexto apache puede escribir en estos archivos/carpetas
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/misitio/uploads -R
```

Comment: Entonces,¿solo tengo que usar esos comandos? Por cierto,cuando uso el primer comando los archivos salen color verde

Comment: `-Z` te tiene que mostrar el contexto de cada archivo o carpeta, si no aparece el contexto de apache ( onda `system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t ` ) para el archivo que queres servir, apache no lo podrá usar

Comment: antes de copiar y pegar los comandos, revisa documentación para ver que sea lo que estas buscando hacer, por ejemplo un enlace en español: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/es-ES/Fedora/11/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html  visto en [gugl](https://www.google.com/search?q=centos+selinux+contextos+apache)

Comment: Otra pregunta: Cuando pones /misitio ¿te refieres al nombre de la carpeta donde están los archivos de la pagina web o es el nombre especifico de un archivo dentro de esa carpeta?

Comment: es una carpeta, por lo general uso siempre subcarpetas ( que habitualmente son symlinks al ./public del source) para tener varios dominios/subdominios en el mismo server