# La opción "-Z" para el comando [ls] retorna 5 columnas, explicación de la cuarta plis

Tags: shell

si corremos el comando
`ls -Z /directorio1/directorio2/index.php`
éste retorna

```
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 /dir1/dir2/index.php
```

es decír:

```
[chmod] [dueño] [grupo] unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 [path/nombre]
```

por favor me explican la parte

**unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0**

los **:** dividen CUATRO columnas?, por que están agrupadas? qué es cada una?

parece que la parte **unconfined_u** indica un "usuario de contexto", cuantos usuarios de contexto existen por defecto?, con que comando lo cambio?, cuál es el criterio paa cambiarlo?

la mísma info la obtengo con el comando **stat**, pero no la sé interpretar.

gracias

Comment: son atributos de [SELiunx](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux), usuario, role, type, sec level, se pueden cambiar con [`chcon`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) o [`semanage fcontext`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/semanage)

Comment: gracias, entonces son separados por medio de los **:** ?, cuales son los `usuarios`por defecto?

Comment: gracias @alo_Malbarez, he logrado CAMBIAR el contexto con éste comando: `chcon system_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 /dir1/dir2/index.php`

Comment: si estás configurando apache fijate esta respuesta q tiene un link en español en los comentarios https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/389775/81450

Comment: copio el enlace por aquí https://docs.fedoraproject.org/es-ES/Fedora/11/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html